# Project's custom variable using plugin in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm building my first plugin and I meet an issue with some variables. I've made some custom fields to store some variables `'project_actitle'` dedicated to a project. The plugin uses these variables. The error appears when either I launch Qgis and there is not any project, or when I use a project that doesn't have these customs fields. That logical, because the plugin doesn't find the field `'project_actitle'`

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
title_file = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(project).variable('project_actitle')
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.10/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\xdr_import_photo\xdr_import_photo.py", line 296, in run
    self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setText(path + folder +  title_file + ".shp")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

How can I avoid this error? I would like to check if the project own this fields and pass the "variable called"  to avoid the error or something like that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you try to concatenate `None` with a string. So the solution is simple: just check if title_file is `None`, and set a default string value.

```
project = QgsProject.instance()
title_file = QgsExpressionContextUtils.projectScope(project).variable('project_actitle')
if title_file is None:
    title_file = "my_default_value"
```

Depending on whether the `title_file` variable is used elsewhere, and should be kept as `None`, you could also change the following line

```
self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setText(path + folder +  title_file + ".shp")
```

to

```
if title_file is None:
    self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setText("")
else:
    self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setText(path + folder +  title_file + ".shp")
```

Comment: Very complete answer with explanation ! thanks